# DevExpress SpreadSheetControl Chart set line color /style

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, spreadsheet

DevExpress website is unable to tell me. How can I influence the line color, thickness, etc. of created graphs?

```
Dim chart As Chart = myworb.Worksheets(1).Charts.Add(Charts.ChartType.ScatterLine)
chart.TopLeftCell = myworb.Worksheets(1).Cells("A83")
chart.BottomRightCell = myworb.Worksheets(1).Cells("F112")
chart.PlotArea.Fill.SetNoFill()

chart.Series.Add(myworb.Worksheets(1)("A1:A71"), myworb.Worksheets(1)("B1:B71"))
chart.Series.Add(myworb.Worksheets(1)("D1:D81"), myworb.Worksheets(1)("E1:E81"))
chart.Series.Add(myworb.Worksheets(1)("G1:G81"), myworb.Worksheets(1)("H1:H81"))
chart.Series.Add(myworb.Worksheets(1)("J1:J71"), myworb.Worksheets(1)("K1:K71"))
chart.Series.Add(myworb.Worksheets(1)("M1:M66"), myworb.Worksheets(1)("N1:N66"))

chart.Title.Visible = False
Dim axisX = chart.PrimaryAxes(0)
axisX.MajorTickMarks = AxisTickMarks.None
axisX.Scaling.AutoMax = False
axisX.Scaling.AutoMin = False
axisX.Scaling.Max = maxX1
axisX.Scaling.Min = minX1

Dim axisY = chart.PrimaryAxes(1)
axisY.MajorTickMarks = AxisTickMarks.None
axisY.Scaling.AutoMax = False
axisY.Scaling.AutoMin = False
axisY.Scaling.Max = maxY1
axisY.Scaling.Min = minY1
```

Normally I would just create an Excelfile as a template, load it into the control an just fill the values the chart is using as a series. But as I have to scale it manually because Excel autoscale is NOT WORKING, I have to create the whole chart from scratch. I am unable to find information about how I can set colors etc in the chart programatically. Any help is greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color and thickness by using [`ShapeFormat.Outline`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressSpreadsheetChartsShapeFormat_Outlinetopic) property of your series objects. Call to [`ShapeOutlineFill.SetSolidFill`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpressSpreadsheetDrawingsShapeOutlineFill_SetSolidFilltopic.aspx) method to set the color of your line and use the [`ShapeOutline.Width`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressSpreadsheetDrawingsShapeOutline_Widthtopic) property to set the line width.
Here is example:

```
chart.Series(5).Outline.SetSolidFill(Color.Magenta)
chart.Series(5).Outline.Width = 20
```

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond. Thanks for you helpfull post. I can set the color as you described in your example. However, Outline.With has no effect on the linewidth.

Comment: @Lorgarn `Outline.Width` has effect if you save your spreadsheet to file and open it in Microsoft Excel directly.

Comment: EDIT: I was mistaken, its just the DevExpress SpreadSheetControl, which is unable to draw Lines in different width. The exported Excel Sheet is using the correct width when opend in Excel. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The "lines" are the chart series and can be accessed in the [`Series`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_Seriestopic) property.  From there you can change various things about the series including the color.  Alternatively you can custom draw series yourself using the [`CustomDrawSeries`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_CustomDrawSeriestopic) event.